to_crs method does not seem to change the projection correctly in GeoPandas
I am trying to project a .shp file from ESRI:102020 to ESRI:4326 (WGS 84).
This is my code:
import geopandas as gpd

mpa = gpd.read_file(fn)
mpa1 = mpa.to_crs("epsg:4326")

When plotting the original file, it all seems to look correct (Ross Sea)
mpa.plot()


However, when plotting the projected GeoDataFrame I get this:
mpa1.plot()


It seems like I got the projection wrong somehow with the areas stretched across longitudes or overlapping, which should not be the case since these areas are confined to the Ross Sea region.
My final goal is to obtain a boolean mask using regionmask.mask_geopandas, but as of now, that seems a little far off.
Here are the .crs of the original file:
<Projected CRS: ESRI:102020>
Name: South_Pole_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- [north]: Easting (metre)
- [north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Coordinate Operation:
- name: unnamed
- method: Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

And of the projected file:
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World.
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich


I used:
mpa.plot()

4326 is not particularly good for data near the poles

What is a better alternative to convert metres to lat/lon?

Using latitude and longitude for the XY coordinate system is inappropriate in many cases for polar regions such as Ross Sea.
Also, as you indicated, the plots are broken because your AOI straddles 180 degrees longitude.
If you need to combine it with another dataset, you should align the other dataset with the appropriate CRS, such as ESRI:102020.
